# Can I make the columns of this table wider, also can the Caption at the bottom not contain Table 1?

Tags: tables

Can I make the columns of this table wider, also can the Caption at the bottom not contain Table 1?

```
  % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet3'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{llllll}
        \multicolumn{6}{l}{Table 3.1: Summary Statistics} \bigstrut[b]\\
        \hline
               & Mean   & Std.   &        & Mean   & Std. \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        $r$    & 0.61   & 4.24   & ElcEq  & 0.79   & 6.02 \bigstrut[t]\\
        Agric  & 0.58   & 6.32   & Autos  & 0.60   & 6.37 \\
        Food   & 0.66   & 4.14   & Aero   & 0.88   & 6.52 \\
        Beer   & 0.69   & 4.98   & Ships  & 0.65   & 6.71 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}%
      \caption{Note: In this Caption I do not want to see the table}
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you add a manual table number instead of using the caption command? If you want the caption to be as wide as the table, take a look at `threeparttable`. This package might also be useful to add table notes.

Comment: What's the reason for `\bigstrut[b]`?

Comment: @leandriis I wish it wasnt there, it comes up when I use excel2latex

Comment: Ok, well then remove it. What about the desired alignment of "Table 3.1: Summary Statistics"? Could you please comment on that? Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also specify which column you want  to make wider and why.

Comment: @leandriis I would like to make all of the columns wider in order to match the notes at the bottom as I think it looks better

Comment: But how wide are the notes? Why not introduce linebreaks in the notes to make them fit the width of the table?

Comment: @learndriis because I think the table looks squashed, is it not possible to make every column say 3cm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\tabcolsep` defines the length between columns.  In the example below, it is fixed to 2em.  You can change this value to fit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}

  \caption{Summary Statistics}\label{tab:addlabel}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{llllll}
      \toprule
      & Mean   & Std.   &        & Mean   & Std.\\
      \midrule
      $r$    & 0.61   & 4.24   & ElcEq  & 0.79   & 6.02 \\
      Agric  & 0.58   & 6.32   & Autos  & 0.60   & 6.37 \\
      Food   & 0.66   & 4.14   & Aero   & 0.88   & 6.52 \\
      Beer   & 0.69   & 4.98   & Ships  & 0.65   & 6.71 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples:

[image]

I would not recomment to artificially make the individual table columns wider than they naturally are.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{A section title}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Summary Statistics}
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
        \begin{tabular}{*{6}{Wc{2cm}}}
        \toprule
               & Mean   & Std.   &        & Mean   & Std. \\
        \midrule
        $r$    & 0.61   & 4.24   & ElcEq  & 0.79   & 6.02 \\
        Agric  & 0.58   & 6.32   & Autos  & 0.60   & 6.37 \\
        Food   & 0.66   & 4.14   & Aero   & 0.88   & 6.52 \\
        Beer   & 0.69   & 4.98   & Ships  & 0.65   & 6.71 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \caption*{Note: In this Caption I do not want to see the table}
    \end{table}%


    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
      \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Summary Statistics}
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
        \begin{tabular}{*{2}{lcc}}
        \toprule
               & Mean   & Std.   &        & Mean   & Std. \\
        \midrule
        $r$    & 0.61   & 4.24   & ElcEq  & 0.79   & 6.02 \\
        Agric  & 0.58   & 6.32   & Autos  & 0.60   & 6.37 \\
        Food   & 0.66   & 4.14   & Aero   & 0.88   & 6.52 \\
        Beer   & 0.69   & 4.98   & Ships  & 0.65   & 6.71 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
%        \end{threeparttable}
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \setlength\labelsep{0pt}
        \item[]Note: In this Caption I do not want to see the table
        \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\sisetup{table-format=1.2}
    \centering
   \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:addlabel}    
    \begin{tabular*}{0.8\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lSSlSS}
      \toprule
        & {Mean} & {Std.} &        & {Mean} & {Std.}    \\
      \midrule
$r$     & 0.61   & 4.24   & ElcEq  & 0.79   & 6.02      \\
Agric   & 0.58   & 6.32   & Autos  & 0.60   & 6.37      \\
Food    & 0.66   & 4.14   & Aero   & 0.88   & 6.52      \\
Beer    & 0.69   & 4.98   & Ships  & 0.65   & 6.71      \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}\small
\note{some explanation about table}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```