# Shift notes left when using \threeparttable

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I have a table and I would like to move the notes to the table right?

Is this possible?

Picture of Table:

[image]

Tex Code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-1in}\caption{Don't ask}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
    \hspace*{-1in}\begin{tabular}{p{4.145em}p{4.145em}lp{4.145em}llp{4.145em}ll}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{p{12.435em}}{$h=1$} & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.435em}}{$h=12$} & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.435em}}{$h=60$} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Ind    & $\hat{\lambda}$ & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.145em}}{$R^2$} & Ind    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.145em}}{\hat{\lambda}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.145em}}{$\R^2$} & Ind    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.145em}}{\hat{\lambda}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.145em}}{$R^2$} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Ag  & \textbf{9.82*} & 0.43   & Ag  & 1.79   & 0.09   & Agric  & -0.23  & 0.03 \bigstrut\\
    Frr   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.09} & 0.1    & Frr   & -0.67  & 0.03   & Frr   & -0.29  & 0.05 \\
    Brr   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5.97} & 0.26   & Brr   & 2.23   & 0.2    & Brr   & 0.39   & 0.06 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
 \begin{tablenotes}
\hspace*{-1in}\item{Notes: In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: `\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \setlength\labelsep{0pt}
        \item[]Note:...`should work. (See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539880/134144)

Comment: Why is there an `\hspace*{-1in}` right before `\begin{tabular}`?

Comment: @leandriis thanks but this did not seem to work

Comment: @leandriis to move the table into the margin

Comment: @leandriis so the table is moved into the margin using the hspace but the notes remain inside

Comment: Please make your example code compilable. Also, why do you need to shift the table into the margin in the first place? The contents are most likely small enough that the table should fit into the margins. If you whish to have quite wide cells, why don' your entirely remove column 4 and 7? They seem to be identical to column 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're abusing and misusing the `threeparttable` machinery. For one, you're not actually including the `\caption` directive -- one of the three formal parts of a `threepartable` -- in the `threeparttable` environment. Second, if your objective is to typeset a table that's considerably wider than the text block, you should go about this quite differently from what you show in your posting. Third, the primary purpose of the `tablenotes` environment is to typeset footnote text associated with `\tnote` directives; however, your code doesn't include any `\tnote`s.

I also don't understand why you employ fixed-width `p`-type columns instead of `X`-type columns (provided by the `tabularx` package).

The following screenshot shows two separate solutions that employ `tabularx` environments. The first uses a `threeparttable` environment (with `\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]`); the second does *not* -- and thereby demonstrates that it's not necessary to deploy the `threeparttable` machinery in order to achieve your formatting objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,bigstrut}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Solution with \texttt{threeparttable}} 
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{9}{X} @{}}
\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{$h=1$} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{$h=12$} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{$h=60$}\bigstrut\\
\hline
    Ind    & $\hat{\lambda}$ & $R^2$ & 
    Ind    & $\hat{\lambda}$ & $R^2$ & 
    Ind    & $\hat{\lambda}$ & $R^2$\bigstrut\\
\hline
    Ag  & \textbf{9.82*} & 0.43   & Ag  & 1.79   & 0.09   & Agric  & -0.23  & 0.03\bigstrut\\
    Frr   & 3.09 & 0.1    & Frr   & -0.67  & 0.03   & Frr   & -0.29  & 0.05 \\
    Brr   & 5.97 & 0.26   & Brr   & 2.23   & 0.2    & Brr   & 0.39   & 0.06 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[]Notes: In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Solution without \texttt{threeparttable}}\label{tab:2}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{9}{X} @{}}
\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{$h=1$} &
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{$h=12$} &
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{$h=60$}\bigstrut\\
\hline
    Ind    & $\hat{\lambda}$ & $R^2$ &
    Ind    & $\hat{\lambda}$ & $R^2$ &
    Ind    & $\hat{\lambda}$ & $R^2$\bigstrut\\
\hline
    Ag  & \textbf{9.82*} & 0.43   & Ag  & 1.79   & 0.09   & Agric  & -0.23  & 0.03\bigstrut\\
    Frr   & 3.09 & 0.1    & Frr   & -0.67  & 0.03   & Frr   & -0.29  & 0.05 \\
    Brr   & 5.97 & 0.26   & Brr   & 2.23   & 0.2    & Brr   & 0.39   & 0.06 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
Notes: In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper In this paper in this paper in this paper.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```